# Store w3c date in POSTGRES

Tags: postgresql

I have a datetime object from a sitemap in this format -

```
2014-12-29 05:00:38-05:00
```

How can I store this datetime in POSTGRES?

Comment: What about [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33570846/3001761)? Did you get bored and wander off? If it's no longer an issue, delete the question.

Comment: @Jon:: Thats the python version of it, I thought its 2 different topics and raised a separate question in POSTGRES

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-DATETIME-INPUT

Answer (score 0):

Use [`timestamp  with time zone`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html):

```
CREATE TABLE tab(col timestamp  with time zone);

INSERT INTO tab
VALUES ('2014-12-29 05:00:38-05:00');

SELECT *
FROM tab;
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9e6fa/1/0)**</kbd>